# Esconder dois div do formulário em php

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update

**Este é o código que tinha:**

```
<?php  
$servername = "xxx.xxx.x.xx";
$username = "xxxxxx";
$password = "xxxxxxxx";
$dbname = "xxxxxxxxx";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
$conn->set_charset('utf8');

$data = $_POST['DataSaida'];
$funcionario = $_POST['Funcionario'];
$funcao = $_POST['Funcao']; 
$tipoluva = $_POST['TipoLuva']; 
$tamanho = $_POST['Tamanho'];
$quantidade = $_POST['Quantidade']; 
$observacoes = $_POST['Observacoes'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO RegSaidaLuvas (`DataSaida`,`Funcionario`,`Funcao`,`TipoLuva`,`Tamanho`,`Quantidade`,`Observacoes`) 
VALUES ('$data','$funcionario','$funcao','$tipoluva','$tamanho','$quantidade','$observacoes')";

 if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE);

$sql1 = "UPDATE StockLuvas SET StockLuvas.Quantidade = StockLuvas.Quantidade -" . $quantidade . " WHERE StockLuvas.Tamanho = {$IdTamanho} AND StockLuvas.TipoLuva= {$IdTipoLuva};";

 if ($conn->query($sql1) === TRUE);

$rowCount = $query->num_rows;

$conn->close();
 ?>
```

**O formulário:**

```html
<form name="form4" method="POST" onsubmit="return form_validation()" >
 
 <h1><center><strong>Saída de Luvas</strong></center></h1></br>
 
    <p><h5><strong>Data de Saída</strong></h5> <input id="DataSaida" type="date" name="DataSaida" required="" ></p></br>

    <label for=""><h5><strong>Funcionario</strong></h5></label>
    <select id="Funcionario" name="Funcionario">
 
   <option value="0">Selecione Produto</option>

      <option value="1">XXX</option>

      <option value="2">XXXXX</option>

      
    </select>
 </br>
 </br>

     <p><h5><strong>Função</strong></h5> <div id="Funcao" name="Funcao"></div></p></br>
  
  <p><h5><strong>Tipo de Luvas</strong></h5> <div id="TipoLuva" name="TipoLuva"></div></p></br>
  
  <p><h5><strong>Tamanho</strong></h5> <div id="Tamanho" name="Tamanho"></div></p></br>
  
  <p><h5><strong>Quantidade</strong></h5> <input type="text" id="Quantidade" name="Quantidade" required="" size="40" /><br/></p></br>
  
  <p><h5><strong>Observações</strong></h5></br>
<textarea type="text" id="Observacoes" name="Observacoes" rows="2" cols="90"></textarea><br/></p></br>
  
 <input type="submit" value="Registar"/>
</form>

    <script>

      var Funcionario = document.getElementById('Funcionario');
      var Funcao = document.getElementById('Funcao');
      var food = [[''], ['AAD'], ['AAD'], ['AAD'], ['AAD'], ['AAD'], ['AAD'], ['AAD'], ['Enfermagem'], ['Estágio'], ['AAD'], ['AAD'], ['Fisioterapia'], ['AAD'], ['AAD'], ['AAD'], ['AAD'], ['Pedologista'], ['AAD'], ['Estágio'], ['AAD'], ['AAD'], ['AAD'], ['AAD'], ['AAD'], ['AAD'], ['AAD'], ['AAD'], ['AAD'], ['AAD'], ['AAD'], ['AAD'], ['AAD'], ['AAD'], ['Outro']];
     
   var TipoLuva = document.getElementById('TipoLuva');
      var food1 = [[''], ['Vinil s/ pó'], ['Vinil s/ pó'], ['Nitrilo'], ['Vinil s/ pó'], ['Vinil s/ pó'], ['Vinil s/ pó'], ['Vinil s/ pó'], ['Vinil s/ pó'], ['Nitrilo'], ['Vinil s/ pó'], ['Vinil s/ pó'], ['Vinil s/ pó'], ['Vinil s/ pó'], ['Nitrilo'], ['Vinil s/ pó'], ['Vinil s/ pó'], ['Vinil s/ pó'], ['Vinil s/ pó'], ['Vinil s/ pó'], ['Vinil s/ pó'], ['Nitrilo'], ['Nitrilo'], ['Vinil s/ pó'], ['Nitrilo'], ['Vinil s/ pó'], ['Nitrilo'], ['Nitrilo'], ['Vinil s/ pó'], ['Nitrilo'], ['Vinil s/ pó'], ['Nitrilo'], ['Nitrilo'], ['Vinil s/ pó'], ['Nitrilo']];
     
   var Tamanho = document.getElementById('Tamanho');
      var food2 = [[''], ['M'], ['L'], ['L'], ['L'], ['M'], ['M'], ['M'], ['S'], ['M'], ['M'], ['M'], ['M'], ['M'], ['M'], ['L'], ['M'], ['M'], ['M'], ['M'], ['M'], ['L'], ['M'], ['M'], ['L'], ['L'], ['M'], ['M'], ['L'], ['M'], ['S'], ['M'], ['M'], ['M'], ['L']];

   Funcionario.onchange = getFood;
   

      function getFood() {

        var val = this.value;

        var html_str = '<select name="Funcao">';

        for (var i = 0, len = food[val].length; i < len; i++) {

          html_str += '<option>' + food[val][i]  + '</option>';
    

        }
  

        html_str += '</select>';

        Funcao.innerHTML = html_str;
  
  
 
  
  
  var html_str = '<select name="TipoLuva">';

        for (var i = 0, len = food1[val].length; i < len; i++) {

          html_str += '<option>' + food1[val][i]  + '</option>';
    

        }
  

        html_str += '</select>';

        TipoLuva.innerHTML = html_str;
  
  
  
  
  var html_str = '<select name="Tamanho">';

        for (var i = 0, len = food2[val].length; i < len; i++) {

          html_str += '<option>' + food2[val][i]  + '</option>';
    

        }
  

        html_str += '</select>';

        Tamanho.innerHTML = html_str;

      }
  

    </script>
```

Mas não conseguia fazer o `update` na tabela StockLuvas com os campos: Id, IdLuvas, TipoLuvas, IdTamanho, Tamanho e Quantidade, porque na parte do `where` do `update` não tinha as variáveis do `$IdLuvas` nem a `$IdTamanho` no formulário e pelo nomes não conseguia.

**Então acrescentei as seguintes variáveis ao código e alterei o update:**

```
$IdTipoLuva = $_POST['IdTipoLuva'];   
$IdTamanho = $_POST['IdTamanho'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO RegSaidaLuvas (`DataSaida`,`Funcionario`,`Funcao`,`IdTipoLuva`,`TipoLuva`,`IdTamanho`,`Tamanho`,`Quantidade`,`Observacoes`) 
VALUES ('$data','$funcionario','$funcao','$IdTipoLuva','$tipoluva','$IdTamanho','$tamanho','$quantidade','$observacoes')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE);

$sql1 = "UPDATE StockLuvas SET StockLuvas.Quantidade = StockLuvas.Quantidade -" . $quantidade . " WHERE StockLuvas.IdTamanho = {$IdTamanho} AND StockLuvas.IdLuvas = {$IdTipoLuva};";

 if ($conn->query($sql1) === TRUE);
```

**E acrescentei dois novos `select` ao formulário para obter as variáveis que criei acima:**

```html
<form name="form4" method="POST" onsubmit="return form_validation()" >
 
 <h1><center><strong>Saída de Luvas</strong></center></h1></br>
 
    <p><h5><strong>Data de Saída</strong></h5> <input id="DataSaida" type="date" name="DataSaida" required="" ></p></br>

    <label for=""><h5><strong>Funcionario</strong></h5></label>
    <select id="Funcionario" name="Funcionario">
 
   <option value="0">Selecione Produto</option>

      <option value="1">xxxx</option>

      <option value="2">xxxxx</option>

      <option value="3">xxxxxx</option>
   
    </select>
 </br>
 </br>

     <p><h5><strong>Função</strong></h5> <div id="Funcao" name="Funcao"></div></p></br>
  
  <p><h5><strong>Código de Luvas</strong></h5> <div id="IdTipoLuva" name="IdTipoLuva"></div></p></br>
  
  <p><h5><strong>Tipo de Luvas</strong></h5> <div id="TipoLuva" name="TipoLuva"></div></p></br>
  
  <p><h5><strong>Código do Tamanho</strong></h5> <div id="IdTamanho" name="IdTamanho"></div></p></br>
  
  <p><h5><strong>Tamanho</strong></h5> <div id="Tamanho" name="Tamanho"></div></p></br>
  
  <p><h5><strong>Quantidade</strong></h5> <input type="text" id="Quantidade" name="Quantidade" required="" size="40" /><br/></p></br>
  
  <p><h5><strong>Observações</strong></h5></br>
<textarea type="text" id="Observacoes" name="Observacoes" rows="2" cols="90"></textarea><br/></p></br>
  
 <input type="submit" value="Registar"/>
</form>

    <script>

      var Funcionario = document.getElementById('Funcionario');
      var Funcao = document.getElementById('Funcao');
      var food = [[''], ['AAD'], ['AAD'], ['AAD'], ['AAD'], ['AAD'], ['AAD'], ['AAD'], ['Enfermagem'], ['Estágio'], ['AAD'], ['AAD'], ['Fisioterapia'], ['AAD'], ['AAD'], ['AAD'], ['AAD'], ['Pedologista'], ['AAD'], ['Estágio'], ['AAD'], ['AAD'], ['AAD'], ['AAD'], ['AAD'], ['AAD'], ['AAD'], ['AAD'], ['AAD'], ['AAD'], ['AAD'], ['AAD'], ['AAD'], ['AAD'], ['Outro']];
      var IdTipoLuva = document.getElementById('IdTipoLuva');
      var food3 = [[''], ['1'], ['1'], ['5'], ['1'], ['1'], ['1'], ['1'], ['1'], ['5'], ['1'], ['1'], ['1'], ['1'], ['5'], ['1'], ['1'], ['1'], ['1'], ['1'], ['1'], ['5'], ['5'], ['1'], ['5'], ['1'], ['5'], ['5'], ['1'], ['5'], ['1'], ['5'], ['5'], ['1'], ['5']];
   var TipoLuva = document.getElementById('TipoLuva');
      var food1 = [[''], ['Vinil s/ pó'], ['Vinil s/ pó'], ['Nitrilo'], ['Vinil s/ pó'], ['Vinil s/ pó'], ['Vinil s/ pó'], ['Vinil s/ pó'], ['Vinil s/ pó'], ['Nitrilo'], ['Vinil s/ pó'], ['Vinil s/ pó'], ['Vinil s/ pó'], ['Vinil s/ pó'], ['Nitrilo'], ['Vinil s/ pó'], ['Vinil s/ pó'], ['Vinil s/ pó'], ['Vinil s/ pó'], ['Vinil s/ pó'], ['Vinil s/ pó'], ['Nitrilo'], ['Nitrilo'], ['Vinil s/ pó'], ['Nitrilo'], ['Vinil s/ pó'], ['Nitrilo'], ['Nitrilo'], ['Vinil s/ pó'], ['Nitrilo'], ['Vinil s/ pó'], ['Nitrilo'], ['Nitrilo'], ['Vinil s/ pó'], ['Nitrilo']];
      var IdTamanho = document.getElementById('IdTamanho');
      var food4 = [[''], ['2'], ['3'], ['3'], ['3'], ['2'], ['2'], ['2'], ['1'], ['2'], ['2'], ['2'], ['2'], ['2'], ['2'], ['3'], ['2'], ['2'], ['2'], ['2'], ['2'], ['3'], ['2'], ['2'], ['3'], ['3'], ['2'], ['2'], ['3'], ['2'], ['1'], ['2'], ['2'], ['2'], ['3']];
   var Tamanho = document.getElementById('Tamanho');
      var food2 = [[''], ['M'], ['L'], ['L'], ['L'], ['M'], ['M'], ['M'], ['S'], ['M'], ['M'], ['M'], ['M'], ['M'], ['M'], ['L'], ['M'], ['M'], ['M'], ['M'], ['M'], ['L'], ['M'], ['M'], ['L'], ['L'], ['M'], ['M'], ['L'], ['M'], ['S'], ['M'], ['M'], ['M'], ['L']];

   Funcionario.onchange = getFood;
   

      function getFood() {

        var val = this.value;

        var html_str = '<select name="Funcao">';

        for (var i = 0, len = food[val].length; i < len; i++) {

          html_str += '<option>' + food[val][i]  + '</option>';
    

        }
  

        html_str += '</select>';

        Funcao.innerHTML = html_str;
  
  
  var html_str = '<select name="IdTipoLuva">';

        for (var i = 0, len = food3[val].length; i < len; i++) {

          html_str += '<option>' + food3[val][i]  + '</option>';
    

        }
  

        html_str += '</select>';

        IdTipoLuva.innerHTML = html_str;
  
  
  var html_str = '<select name="TipoLuva">';

        for (var i = 0, len = food1[val].length; i < len; i++) {

          html_str += '<option>' + food1[val][i]  + '</option>';
    

        }
  

        html_str += '</select>';

        TipoLuva.innerHTML = html_str;
  
  
  var html_str = '<select name="IdTamanho">';

        for (var i = 0, len = food4[val].length; i < len; i++) {

          html_str += '<option>' + food4[val][i]  + '</option>';
    

        }
  

        html_str += '</select>';

        IdTamanho.innerHTML = html_str;
  
  
  var html_str = '<select name="Tamanho">';

        for (var i = 0, len = food2[val].length; i < len; i++) {

          html_str += '<option>' + food2[val][i]  + '</option>';
    

        }
  

        html_str += '</select>';

        Tamanho.innerHTML = html_str;

      }
  

    </script>
```

Mas agora quando seleciono o funcionário esses `select` também aparecem, onde não são precisos para o utilizador que vai preencher o formulário, só preciso para fazer o `update`na tabela do stock e `inserir` na tabela dos RegSaidaLuvas, como posso ocultar esses dois `select` do código de Luvas e do código de tamanho no formulário para o utilizador não os ver? Ao selecionar o funcionário os atributos que aparecem nos `select` são de acordo com o que o funcionário utiliza, tanto na função, no tipo de luvas como no tamanho.

Answer (score -1):

Cara, coloque os campos IdTipoLuva e IdTamanho em inputs do tipo hidden, que não serão exibidos para o usuário (ele ainda poderá visualizar no código fonte).

Outra coisa, não pode haver dois elementos com o mesmo ID no HTML, portanto não utilize o ID IdTipoLuva e IdTamanho para o input e para a DIV container dele, tente utilizar nomes diferentes.

Comment: Pode colocar um exemplo?